# Как выдернуть параметры командной строки?

Tags: java, строки, запуск

Есть строка для запуска программы
Пример запуска: java -jar program.jar search input.json output.json
Как из неё выдернуть параметры: search, input.json, output.json?
Для запуска программы

Comment: А как осуществить запуск программы непосредственно? По решению ниже?

Comment: Ваш пример запуска подойдет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из входной точки. Параметр `args` содержит аргументы при запуске.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (String arg : args) {
      System.out.println(arg);
  }
}
```